# Gradle application plugin with main class in non-main source set

Tags: gradle

Documentation says

> [You can run the application by executing the run task (type: JavaExec). This will compile the main source set, and launch a new JVM with its classes (along with all runtime dependencies) as the classpath and using the specified main class. You can launch the application in debug mode with gradle run --debug-jvm (see JavaExec.setDebug(boolean)).](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

In my case the main class is not in the main source set but in `jmh` (I wanted to quickly try some things without going through the JMH infrastructure using classes defined there). Can I still use the application plugin?

Simply using `./gradlew :benchmarks:run` gives "could not find or load main class `MyMainClass`", as expected. `:jmhRun` (by analogy with other tasks) gives "task 'jmhRun' not found in project 'benchmarks'". `:runJmh` is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not possible (Gradle 5.0) as the name of the `main` source set is not configurable in the `org.gradle.api.plugins.ApplicationPlugin#addRunTask`. I've created an issue there https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8113.

UPD: as was suggested in the gradle issue

```
tasks.named('run', JavaExec) {
    classpath = <wanted classpath>
}
```